# How to convert HashMap to ArrayList in Kotlin

Tags: android, arraylist, hashmap

I receive a HashMap like this, which I am trying to convert to an ArrayList

```kotlin
var snapshot = it.result!!.value as HashMap<String, Any>
val addresses: ArrayList<Address> = ArrayList<Address>(snapshot.values)
```

Error:

```
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.
<init>((MutableCollection<out TypeVariable(E)!>..Collection<TypeVariable(E)!>?))   where E = TypeVariable(E) for    fun <E> <init>(c: (MutableCollection<out E!>..Collection<E!>?)): kotlin.collections.ArrayList<E> /* = java.util.ArrayList<E> */ defined in kotlin.collections.ArrayList
<init>(Int)   where E = TypeVariable(E) for    fun <E> <init>(initialCapacity: Int): kotlin.collections.ArrayList<E> /* = java.util.ArrayList<E> */ defined in kotlin.collections.ArrayList
```

I need to assign this list to the recyclerview adapter.

```kotlin
addressesAdapter = AddressAdapter(arrlstAddresses)
```

AddressAdapter class:

```kotlin
class AddressAdapter(private val addressList: ArrayList<Address>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<AddressAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
   ...
}
```

Address class:

```
class Address(
var addressLine1: String = "",
var addressLine2: String = "",
var city: String = "",
var state: String = "",
var pinCode: String = "",
) {}
```

Comment: You simply can not convert a `HashMap<String, Any>` to an `ArrayList<Address>` . Whats the type `Address` here ? If `HashMap`  value is `Address` then just loop through the hasmap and cast value to `Address` and add it to a List . If Hash map contains Address why not just have `HashMap<String,Address>`?

Comment: please use this sample - import java.util.ArrayList
import java.util.HashMap

fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    val map = HashMap<Int, String>()
    map.put(1, "a")
    map.put(2, "b")
    map.put(3, "c")
    map.put(4, "d")
    map.put(5, "e")
    map.put(6, "f")

    val keyList = ArrayList(map.keys)
    val valueList = ArrayList(map.values)

    println("Key List: $keyList")
    println("Value List: $valueList")
}

Comment: @HasanuzzamanRana There is no point of adding that much code as comment, its unreadable . If you have the solution better post it as answer.

Answer (score -1):

val beans: List = ArrayList(snapshot.values())

Comment: This doesn't work, "Unresolved reference - values"